# Image is not compressed to less than 307kb. ios9

Tags: ios, uiimage, jpeg, ios9

I am trying to upload image with size of 80 to 100 kb but unfortunately below code is not working as expected,

```
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
```

I have tried to change compression even to 0.001 but `imageData` is not compressed less than 307 kb.

Is there another way to change `UIImage` to `NSData` down to 80-100kb?

Comment: The compression for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation ` is JPG compression. Thus if you have a image 3000x3000 you can change the comression level to what ever it will never become 80kb. So first you need to check you image size.

Comment: thank you @rckoenes  for suggestion, I have successfully compressed image down to 80-100kb after resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First resize the image with below method:

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

call this by:

```
UIImage *newImage=yourImage;
CGSize size=CGSizeMake(newImage.size.width/8,newImage.size.height/8);
newImage=[self resizeImage:newImage newSize:size];
```

And finally compressed your image as required:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.5);
NSLog(@"Size of image = %lu KB",(imageData.length/1024));
```